# libcurl file post in c++, usable example

Tags: c++, c, post, https, libcurl

Is there an example for posting a file with https using libcurl?

I found [this example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html), but I don't think it's doing https POST.

Answer (score 0):

"Posting a file" is not very specific, but if you're talking about a multipart formpost then this example is probably what you want:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-post.html

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this tutorial:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html

Your example is about file uploading